# Template class with no template class twin

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to write template class with this behavior:

```
class Result { /* ... */ };

template<class ResultValue>
class Result { /* ... */ };
```

And use it as return value of some API. Like:

```
Result function1(); // no 'Result' params
Result<WithParam> function2();
```

Comment: How about `Result<void>`?

Comment: You cannot overload classes.

Comment: you can also have a Result<>

Comment: Why not `void function1(...)`?

Comment: @jxh because class Result is much more complex  than I showed in example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A template must be followed by template arguments, except in the case of a template template parameter or CTAD. Sadly, CTAD for return type deduction is not a thing yet.

What you can do instead is to name them differently:

```
class result { /* ... */ };

template<class ResultValue>
class basic_result { /* ... */ };
```

This is analogous to the `std::string` class which is an alias to `std::basic_string<char>`

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like:

```
template <class ResultValue=void>
class Result {/*a certain implementation*/};

template <>
struct Result<void> {/*another implementation*/};

Result<> myResult;
```